# Magento 2.4.4 upgrade after customer login is not working?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.0

I have upgraded the site from magento 2.4.2 to magento 2.4.4.
After the upgrade, the customer login is working fine, but after logging in, if I move to any other pages, the customer logs out automatically. I am not getting any error in system.log or exception.log or debug.log.

Comment: Try to compile one's and check it into different modes.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i have check with all modes and compile the code still i am fetching same problem.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i have found the solution, it's related to varnish.i have set built in cache on full page cache(Caching Application) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

check in your magento database :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

To update the cookie domain, use this query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET VALUE = "domain.com" WHERE path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```